# Why there is no study on the forecasting methods for the exchange rates of CBDCs? What do you think?

Tags: macroeconomics, self-study, exchange-rates, cryptocurrency, cbdc

What do you think about the predictiion/forecasting the exchange rate of CBDCs?

(CBDC= CENTRAL BANK DIGITAL CURRENCY)

I cannot find any paper on this issue in the literature. But, there are some papers and studies on the forecasting methods for the exchange rate of cryptocurrencies.

I am asking the reasons why there is no study on the forecasting the exchange rates of CBDCs? What do you think? Does this issue make no sense?

My thought is that CBDCs are pegged to the value of that country's fiat currency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As of now there are few actual CBDCs in place  China, Bahamas, Jamaica and Nigeria; other countries only have plans to implement them and are still conducting pilot experiments
  (https://blog.chainalysis.com/reports/central-bank-digital-currencies-cbdc/).

You can't statistically forecast something without any data, and maybe there's not enough available data yet.
I think this IMF call for papers (https://www.imf.org/en/News/Seminars/Conferences/2023/11/15/11th-imf-statistical-forum) will probably contain many papers about what you're asking.

- CBDCs are being considered as replacement of current currencies and form of making digital payments (see [ECB](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/digital_euro/html/index.en.html)), so there won't be an exchange between regular paper currency and CBDC (at least not officially). It would be like having money on bank account. There will be exchange rate between other currencies but not between physical money and digital money of the same currency.

Answer (score 0):

There are current working CBDCs in China, the Caribbean countries, and Nigeria.
https://medium.com/@shymaa.arafat/cbdcs-part1-1da3a944722c

(You may check references 14, 23, 29, 30,... and 36)

I study CBDCs from Computer Science and Engineering perspective, so I can't claim I searched for such questions, but I once encounterd this paper that seems too economic for me (and describes CBDCs as subject to inflation and exchange rates variations)

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S027553192300096X

This also could be related to your work more than mine
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/368969492_CBDC_uncertainty_Financial_market_implications

& this one with all the 7 links citing it, I think you can make a thesis in Economy with all those references

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0275531922002513#bib50